# How to support inline comments in PostCSS?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, postcss

Webpack/PostCSS is unable to process .pcss files which have inline comments:

> Module build failed: Syntax Error
>
> ```
> (77:5) Unknown word
>
> > 77 |     //  }
>      |     ^
> ```

PostCSS part of my Webpack's config:

```
let PostCSSConfig = {
        sourceMap: true,
        plugins:   () => [
            require('postcss-smart-import'),
            require('precss')({}),
            require('postcss-for')({}),
            require('postcss-mixins')({}),
            require('postcss-math')({}),
            require('postcss-percentage')({}),
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes')({}),
            require('postcss-cssnext')({browsers: ['> 0.05%', 'IE 7'], cascade: false})
        ]
    };
```

config.module.rules:

```
{
    test: /\.pcss$/,
    exclude: inlineCSS,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: [{
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: PostCSSConfig
            }
        ]
    })
}
```

I tried using following plugins:

- postcss-comment
- postcss-inline-comment
- postcss-scss
- postcss-strip-comments

but none helped, I had errors every time.

Comment: Are you intentionally using double slash `//` comments in CSS or it's just a typo?

Comment: Intentionally. Sass [should support](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Comments________and_____comments) `//`.

Comment: @van_folmert did any of the posted answers help you to fix your problem? If so, would you be kind enough to mark it as an answer please?

Answer (score 14):

You mention `postcss-comment`, apparently, `postcss-comment` is not a PostCSS plugin, it is a **parser**.

In my own projects I was using a PostCSS config file like the following:

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = () => ({
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'postcss-cssnext': {},
        'cssnano': {},
    }
});
```

Install your chosen parser:

```
npm i -D postcss-comment
```

then adding the following line to your config:

```
parser: require('postcss-comment'),
```

that should work.

Your final config will look as follows:

```
module.exports = () => ({
    parser: require('postcss-comment'),

    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'postcss-cssnext': {},
        'cssnano': {},
    }
});
```

The key for me was finding this Github issue: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss/issues/58#issuecomment-318464851

Answer (score 8):

Inline comments (like this: `// I'm a comment!`) are invalid CSS. But they are valid SCSS, so if you want to use them in `.css` files, you'll need to transform those files using a SCSS parser with PostCSS. [PostCSS SCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss) can do this. To use it, set it as PostCSS's parser. Here's an example webpack config:

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "main.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          // Set postcss-scss as the parser, allowing valid SCSS syntax
          { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { parser: "postcss-scss" } }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This will transform the following CSS:

```
// I am an inline comment!
// I'm invalid CSS, but I'll be transformed into a valid block comment.
body {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

into this:

```
/* I am an inline comment!*/
/* I'm invalid CSS, but I'll be transformed into a valid block comment.*/
body {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

And here's a working CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/kxqv1xvlx5

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with this small library I added to the PostCSS eco system:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-strip-inline-comments

```
/* This comment will remain */
// This comment will be removed 
body {
    // This comment will also be removed 
    background-color: black;
}
// And so will this one
```

Answer (score 0):

[postcss-strip-inline-comments](https://github.com/mummybot/postcss-strip-inline-comments) works with *scss syntax* configured (you also need to install [postcss-scss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss)):

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
    syntax: 'postcss-scss',
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-strip-inline-comments'),
        // ...
    ],
}
```